# Can I share a precompiled binary from an Ubuntu VM to a remote server

Tags: virtualization, sharing

I’m pretty new to the whole Linux based system thing and I’m getting the hand of it, but is there a way to upload precompiled binaries from one vm to a cloud vm like AWS.

This is simply because I currently only have one cpu core per server and compiling takes almost a whole day on those machines

Comment: You could package it & host it for other servers, or depending on what it is compile/package it for PPA (compile & package isn't done on your machine anyway) and PPA is available for anyone including yourself.  The PPA is *personal package archive* (ie. 3rd party which includes us)

Comment: But what do you exactly want to do? Compile a program on one machine and then copy it to another machine and run it there? Obviously you can do it, however it's best when the other machine has the same kernel version and all the same libraries installed. Otherwise, it may or may not run on the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: use Docker to build online and then download image and execute on VMs